# ruby on rails seed .yml file which has models with associations in it

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, yaml, seed

I don't really understand how to seed a .yml file which has more than one data model in it, plus they are they are interrelated.

That's what I have:

project.rb

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :todos
end
```

todo.rb

```
class Todo < ActiveRecord::Base

  belongs_to :project

end
```

my data schema:

```
  create_table "projects", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "title"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

  create_table "todos", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "text"
    t.boolean  "isCompleted"
    t.integer  "project_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",  null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",  null: false
  end
```

seeds.rb (ofc it doesn't work)

```
seed_file = File.join(Rails.root, 'db', 'seeds/seeds.yml')
config = YAML::load_file(seed_file)
Project.create(config["projects"])
```

seeds/seeds.yml

```
projects:
 - title: 'family'
   todos:
    - text: 'Get some milk'
      isCompleted: false
    - text: 'Cook some bacon'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Repair the front door'
      isCompleted: false
 - title: 'work'
   todos:
    - text: 'Call my boss'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Finish my work tasks'
      isCompleted: true
    - text: 'Get fired'
      isCompleted: false
 - title: 'therest'
   todos:
    - text: 'Do something'
      isCompleted: false
    - text: 'Ask a question on stackoverflow'
      isCompleted: false
```

Can someone tell me please, what should I do to make it work properly. I need to use exactly this kind of data from my `seeds.yml`, I know how to make two different .yml files for `projects` and `todos` and make them work, but this is not the way I want to solve my problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do yourself a favor, delete the seeds.yml file and create all inside seeds.rb

Comment: As you wish, did it! :) But does it make any sence? What if I have a lot of .yml files, isn't this better to just put them all in one folder?) Just looks the way better.

Comment: yeah in that cases yml files make sense, but at the end you'll have a lot of hashes to do the "Model.create" thing and you can write those hashes directly inside seeds.rb.

BTW, don't use fixtures for testing, use FactoryGirl instead.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you need to separate your models into separate fixture files. Though it says theres some minimal support for setting relationships via YML & seed.rb workflow:

> http://guides.rubyonrails.org/testing.html#the-low-down-on-fixtures

I'd recommend a alternate routes to seed your database unless this is a business requirement essential to follow. Can help more if you answer:

- Do you already have the data you want to supply to db?
- Is your goal to seed a test / dev / or production database?

Comment: This is a business requirement, as I said I already used another way to make everything work, but how to make this one work? :D Thanks for the answer btw. My goal is just to seed that file, to get know how this works.

Comment: Yeah so multi model .yml seed files do not look like they are supported.. I recommend you just use ruby to load & seed the static data you need. ex. http://www.xyzpub.com/en/ruby-on-rails/3.2/seed_rb.html - sorry thats all I can help with without understanding more of biz req. - best